# progress bar with only html and css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a progress bar using only html and css and I can't make the image to move along if the progress bar changes.
For example, if I set it to 25%, 50%, 75%, I want a dot at the end of the progress spectrum.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/10x10">
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.progress {
  height:2px;
  width:300px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar {
  height:2px;
  width:20%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

.progress-bar img {
  position: absolute;  
}
```

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Use the HTML5 progress element: `<progress value="70" max="100">70 %</progress>`

Comment: You want the placeholder image at the end of the progress? Or something else.

Comment: yes, I want that image at the end of the progress. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sumus/2/edit)**

```
.progress {
  height:2px;
  width:300px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar {
  height:2px;
  width:40%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}

.progress-bar img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%:
}
```

Make the image to be `left:100%`

Comment: I want that image at the end of the progress, not stretched. I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear.

Comment: .progress-bar img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}

Comment: Thank you sir :D ...if you could modify your answer so I can mark it as the correct one, it would be nice :)

Comment: Yes, i have modified it :)

Answer (score 0):

I made this one for an old project and it works just fine !

```
#pourcentage {
    width:100px;
    padding:2px;
    background-color:white;
    text-align:center;
    height: 20px;
}
#indicatorValid {
    background-color: #2ecc71;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
}
#indicatorErreur {
    background-color:#E44C41;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
}

  <div id='pourcentage'>
    <div style='width:50px;' id='indicatorValid'>50 %</div>
    <div style='width:50px;' id='indicatorErreur'>50 %</div>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/53Dnd/